# Peewee: select rows if they contain a certain keyword

Tags: python, peewee

Given the following:

```
import datetime

from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase("wl.db")


class Entry(Model):
    my_name = CharField(max_length=100)
    task_name = CharField(max_length=100)
    minutes = IntegerField(default=0)
    notes = CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        database = db


def initialize():
    e = Entry(my_name="bot", task_name="hello world", minutes=12, notes="")
    e.save()
    e = Entry(my_name="bot 2", task_name="random hello random", minutes=1, notes="random")
    e.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Entry], safe=True)
    initialize()
```

Is there a query where I can `select()` all records which contain a certain keyword.
For example: I want to select all records which contain "hello" in there `Entry.task_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following

```
query = Entry.select().where(Entry.task_name.contains('hello'))
```

This is equivalent to doing:

```
query = Entry.select().where(Entry.task_name ** '%hello%')
```

The wild cards ("%") might be different depending on what the backend database is.

Comment: Actually when using "contains" you do not need to include the wildcards!